# When is it better to have more or less html elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, flexbox

The title question sums my thoughts up quite well, but let me explain how i got to this question.

I am working on a navigation bar for a content-heavy social networking site. I'm using flexbox to align the navigation items. First, i wrapped a div tag around all those items, but then I asked myself, why add more code here if i can do it without. Or more generally, is the overall performance getting worse if i have a lot of html elements, especially regarding javascript/jquery. I guess so.. But maybe sometimes, is it wiser to add more elements to have a clearer structure or even mandatory by w3c rules?

The navigation bar HTML code looks like this using the minimum number of elements (i removed most of the ids classes and css here to keep it clear):

```
<body>
    <nav class="flexBox">
        <a class="flexItem">
          <!--icon background image-->
        </a>
        <form class="flexItem">
          <!--search form content-->
        </form>
        <ul class="flexItem">
          <!--some li elements-->
        </ul>
        <div class="flexItem">
            <!--some grouped content-->
        </div>
        <a class="flexItem">
          <!--icon background image-->
        </a>
    </nav>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.flexItem{
  display: block;
}
.flexBox{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}
```

Is it legal to do it like this? Is it wise to do it like this? Is the performance better compared to wrapping divs around it (assuming theres a lot of js going on all over the page).

I didn't find anything about the relation between number of html elements and performance on google. Hope someone here can help me out.

Comment: There's no reason to have unnecessary containers. Use as many as you need, but not more. Using many divs when fewer could achieve the same thing is called _divitis_.

Comment: The best way to get a feel for "good" and "bad" - once you've decided you care, which you have - is to read tutorials from well-respected bloggers etc. about implementing web widgets etc. There's no "best" way to do things, but there are certainly a lot of terrible ways :)

Comment: This is really an opinion-based question, so it should be closed.  My personal opinion though is that the structure you have shown is OK.  You will need to be wary however of possibly needing to change CSS `display` behavior to , for instance make `<a>` block or similar.

Comment: I agree with @Nit. Use what is necessary but also don't drop a div just because it may cause performance issues. Just make sure you have readable code.

Comment: Quick and nice answers, all of you! Thanks. I'd agree with Mike Brant, this question can be closed. But since I didnt find anything on google, it's good to see your answers here for others!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be concerned about the amount of html elements, because realistically most browsers can handle much heavier memory usage than the differences you are talking about.

The javascript side of things can be more of a concern though. If you have many elements and are referencing them with jquery, than can be a lot of memory allocations and that can be a concern. With proper memory management and attention to things like scope and initializations, it shouldn't be a problem for you.

You should use whatever amount of html best suits your task, regardless of how many elements you use.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no limitations with how you structure your document for the browser.

You may structure your code as beautifully and manageable as required. However, you should keep in mind that the associated javascripts written/loaded by you do not cause enough strain on the performance of the document.

For instance, writing some event handler on mouse hover event that might block the browser [considering a loop was scripted or some other long running operation].